# Convert List<List<String>> to String[]

Tags: java, list, arrays

I have a requirement wherein i should write a method of type `String[]` and return the same.But the implementation that i have, uses and returns `List<List<String>>`.Also the `List<List<String>>` gets and returns values from the database and the values are not known prior to add them to the `String[]` directly.The list can also be of a huge size to accomodate it in an `String[]` . How to get this conversion done.

Comment: And how does this "requirement" specify how the data should be laid out in the flat string array, if the logic (presumably also constrained by said "requirement") gets you a list of lists instead?

Comment: if this is homework, please tag it as such

Comment: This looks like a matrix (2D array) of strings, not a 1D array.

Comment: Are you sure this is String[] not String[][]?

Comment: Take a look at my answer that is supplying test code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
public static String[] myMethod(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list) 
{
    int dim1 = list.size(); 
    int total=0;
    for(int i=0; i< dim1; i++)
        total += list.get(i).size();

    String[] result = new String[total];        

    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<dim1; i++)
    {
        int dim2 = list.get(i).size();
        for(int j=0; j<dim2; j++)
        {
            result[index] = list.get(i).get(j);
            index++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Run this test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add("first of first");
        list1.add("second of first");
        list1.add("third of first");

        list2.add("first of second");

        list3.add("first of third");
        list3.add("second of third");

        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> superList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        superList.add(list1);
        superList.add(list2);
        superList.add(list3);

        String[] output = myMethod(superList);

        for(int i=0; i<output.length; i++)
            System.out.println(output[i]);                  
    }
```

Comment: Can you remove your down vote? My code is working for this question.

Comment: It will still fail if the total number of String elements will exceed  Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8 (OutOfMemory) check my comment to the @Percepption answer. Check also the ArrayList implementation (line 190)

Comment: Thanks for the response but as i have mentioned in the question already i donot know the values to be inserted prior to runningh the program.These values are dynamic and are not known before to add them directly as you above in the list.add("first of first");

Comment: I just populated the arraylist to show that it gives desired results. Of course, you will pass your arraylist dynamicallly to the method as a parameter then you will get String[] output upon every invocation of myMethod(). What is not clear about this?

Answer (score 3):

This should work just fine. Though if you can return your embedded list structure that would be even better:

```
final List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>(64000);
final List<List<String>> mainList = yourFuncWhichReturnsEmbeddedLists();
for(final List<String> subList: mainList) {
    resultList.addAll(subList);
}

final String[] resultArr = subList.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: The array size in java is limited by 2147483647 which is max integer. In case the total number of strings in the embedded list exceeds this value you will get an OOM inside the loop. It would be nice to do some size checking prior to the flattening of the embedded list and in case of number of elements in embedded list exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE find some creative way to process the original list in chunks.

Comment: correction to my previos comment: the max array size is Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8 = 2 147 483 639 (taken from java implementation ArrayList line 190)

Comment: Actually, an OOM will only occur in the loop if the JVM runs out of heap space. Ditto for converting the list to an array, though any elements over `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1` will be discarded, based on the logic in `ArrayList.toArray`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but i have tried implementing this code and found that displaying the resultList in the above code is returning the values correctly but when this List<String> is converted to String[] and this string array is displayed it is displaying the object names rather the actual values.Something lik e this is diplayed [Ljava.lang.String;@6894a2

Comment: @user930524: I think you tried to display array directly. You should have iterated through array, read each of the string and then display.

Comment: @aviad: If he has a list with 2^31 strings, I think the maximum array size is the least of his concerns. Unless he's written a weird sparse list of some sort, in the most optimistic case the lists alone would take 16 gigabytes of memory (assuming 64bit - it would get very tricky in a 32bit address space), not to mention the memory taken by the actual strings. Adding checks for insane conditions like that only serves to make code unreadable.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen, as appears in the question "the list can be of huge size". While dealing with big data these situation are not uncommon and there are certain techiniques to deal with large data sets (processing in chunks for example). I think that answer to question must take in account these problematic situation that you mentioned in your comment with 'little sarcasm'.

Comment: @aviad: I don't think `List` is the interface to use for chunked data, because the random access provided by lists kind of implies that all of the data is always available. Unless, of course, he's doing some major trickery with a custom load-on-demand list implementation, which I don't think he is, judging by the level of his question.